# Mysql join query?

Tags: mysql

**ToBeCollected** table

```
Id     Name          Amount
1      MR XXX         10000  
2      Mr YYY         15000
3      Mr ZZZ         12000
```

**Collected** Table

```
ID    Name        Amount
1     Mr XXX       5000
2     Mr XXX       2000
3     Mr YYY      12000
4     Mr YYY       1000
```

What I am looking for is this.

```
ID    Name   ToBeCollected    Collected     Balance
1    Mr XXX     10,000           7,000       3,000
2    Mr YYY     15,000          13,000       2,000
3    Mr ZZZ     12,000               0      12,000
```

Comment: what did you try?

Answer (score 1):

Try this Query....

```
SELECT t.id,t.name,max(t.amt) as tobeCol,
       coalesce(s.amt,0) as Col,
       max(t.amt) - coalesce(s.amt,0) as Balance
FROM ToBeCollected t
LEFT JOIN (select sum(amt) as amt,name from Collected group by name) s on s.name=t.name
group by t.name,t.id;
```

Comment: Why sum twice? Isn't that genarally the same query as mine?

Comment: @sagi ...you should check output of my query

Comment: @SmitaAhinave forget to type alias 't'

Comment: Not seeing any difference from mine beside that extra unnecessary sub query.

Comment: @sagi...collected column should contain 7000 i.e.5000+2000 right? but your query is not giving 7000...Hope now you will understand why I have used subquery..

Comment: Of course it will, thats why the outer sum is for, tell me that - if you already get the sum in the sub query, why sum again outside?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this output using simple `join, max(), GROUP BY`and`IFNULL()` function ,

So your query will be,

```
SELECT ToBeCollected.Id,ToBeCollected.Name,
       max(ToBeCollected.Amount) as ToBeCollected,
       IFNULL(sum(Collected.Amount),0) as Collected,
       max(ToBeCollected.Amount) - IFNULL(sum(Collected.Amount),0) as Balance
   FROM ToBeCollected
   LEFT JOIN Collected ON Collected.Name = ToBeCollected.Name
   GROUP BY ToBeCollected.Id
```

**Note**: Require output you can check on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a374c/29) and you can refer this [Document](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html).

Comment: You need a left join.. Outerwise the isnull won't doanything.

Comment: Thanks Sir @sagi , I Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, the two tables are linked by Name column.
You can try this:

```
SELECT tb.Id, tb.Name, tb.Amount ToBeCollected,
ifnull(SUM(cl.Amount), 0) Collected,
(tb.Amount - ifnull(SUM(cl.Amount), 0)) Balance
FROM ToBeCollected tb LEFT JOIN Collected cl ON (tb.Name = cl.Name)
GROUP BY tb.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
t.ID,
t.name,
t.Amount as ToBeCollected,
if(c.total_amount_collected is null, 0, c.total_amount_collected) as Collected,
if(c.total_amount_collected is null, t.amount, t.amount - c.total_amount_collected)  as Balance
from ToBeCollected t
left join (select Name, sum(Amount) as total_amount_collected from Collected group by Name) as c
on(t.Name = c.Name)
```

the subselect is used to calculate the collected amount as there are multiple rows per name in table_Collected .
the ifs are used to compensate for rows in t that have no corresponding row in c (easy to follow)